# Finish and then start same activity issue

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, lifecycle

In [this Udacity project](https://github.com/udacity/AdvancedAndroid_ClassicalMusicQuiz), there is a strange bug. It blinks notification and then remove when next question is passed.

This is the part where next question comes:

```
 // Wait some time so the user can see the correct answer, then go to the next question.

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mExoPlayer.stop();
        Intent nextQuestionIntent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);
        nextQuestionIntent.putExtra(REMAINING_SONGS_KEY, mRemainingSampleIDs);
        finish();
        startActivity(nextQuestionIntent);

    }
}, CORRECT_ANSWER_DELAY_MILLIS);
```

You see, it starts the same activity (QuizActivity) with some extra data. It also calls finish() to finish this old activity before starting the new one.

However, when I debug the lifecycles, it shows that onDestroy is called after new activity's onCreate is called. It's the cause of the notification's blink and gone forever state because in onDestroy, releasePlayer() method called which causes notification to be gone:

```
private void releasePlayer() {
        Log.i(TAG, "release player and notification cancelled");
        mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
        mExoPlayer.stop();
        mExoPlayer.release();
        mExoPlayer = null;
    }
```

So how strange is that?

Comment: That is a correct behavior, therefore you are the one who need to adjust. If `onDestroy` is called first before `onCreate` that would mean that a blank screen will appear before the next activity shows. :)

Comment: So, I am the strange one to this topic. Can you enlighten me how can I adjust to this? Preventing notification to dissappear?

Comment: then call the releasePlayer in between `mExoPlayer.stop();` and `Intent nextQuestionIntent` instead rather in onDestroy.

Comment: But, this time. I won't be able to remove notification when this activity is left. (back button pressed etc.)

Comment: You can do this in ondestroy: `if(!explicityCallyed){ releasePlayer()}` and in your `run()` code add this extra line of code e.g. `explicitlyCalled = true;`. Don't forget to add a member variable `private explicitylyCalled = false;`

Comment: Sorry for the typos, those variables should be `explicitlyCalled`. If it is not working you can join the [chat](https://discord.gg/CE3X2C) room.